# Data Type mismatch error when using function in SQL Statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a function which gives Levenshtein Distance used for fuzzy search of a field.

```vb
Option Compare Database

' Levenshtein3 tweaked for UTLIMATE speed and CORRECT results
' Solution based on Longs
' Intermediate arrays holding Asc()make difference
' even Fixed length Arrays have impact on speed (small indeed)
' Levenshtein version 3 will return correct percentage
'
Function Levenshtein(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal string2 As String) As Long
1
Dim i As Long, j As Long, string1_length As Long, string2_length As Long
Dim distance(0 To 60, 0 To 50) As Long, smStr1(1 To 60) As Long, smStr2(1 To 50) As Long
Dim min1 As Long, min2 As Long, min3 As Long, minmin As Long, MaxL As Long

string1_length = Len(string1):  string2_length = Len(string2)

distance(0, 0) = 0
For i = 1 To string1_length:    distance(i, 0) = i: smStr1(i) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string1, i, 1))): Next
For j = 1 To string2_length:    distance(0, j) = j: smStr2(j) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string2, j, 1))): Next
For i = 1 To string1_length
    For j = 1 To string2_length
        If smStr1(i) = smStr2(j) Then
            distance(i, j) = distance(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = distance(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = distance(i, j - 1) + 1
            min3 = distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                If min2 < min3 Then minmin = min2 Else minmin = min3
            Else
                If min1 < min3 Then minmin = min1 Else minmin = min3
            End If
            distance(i, j) = minmin
        End If
    Next
Next

' Levenshtein3 will properly return a percent match (100%=exact) based on similarities and Lengths etc...
MaxL = string1_length: If string2_length > MaxL Then MaxL = string2_length
Levenshtein = 100 - CLng((distance(string1_length, string2_length) * 100) / MaxL)

End Function
```

When I try to write a SQL statement like the one below, I get a datatype mismatch error:

```vb
strSQL_1 = "SELECT * FROM Location_Table ORDER BY (Levenshtein([Short_Desc],'Search String')) DESC;"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL_1)
```

Where Short_Desc is a column in the Location_Table with Short Text datatype.

Using `Debug.Print strSQL_1`, this is what's shown in the immediate window:

```
SELECT * FROM Location_Table ORDER BY Levenshtein(Short_Desc,'Search String') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the value of Short_Desc is used, but the fieldname.

Try

```
"SELECT * FROM Location_Table ORDER BY (Levenshtein(" & [Short_Desc] & ",'Search String')) DESC"
```

Comment: This gives the error: Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.

Comment: The syntax of the ORDER BY clause is as follows - **SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;** Your function Levenshtein returns a long integer which SQL interprets as a field name. @Knightowl3128

Comment: @user10186832 So, how do I rewrite this query to sort by my custom function?